# Super Smooth Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I've been trying to create smooth scrolling and trying to get it as smooth as http://lookbook.quechua.com/spring-summer-2016/en/hiking when you scroll down through the products but finding it hard to replicate / find anything else that could help.

At the minute Im using TweenMax and the Scroll To Plugin however this acts differently in Firefox and Chrome and it scrolls a set distance which I really don't want to have to do instead of it feeling like the user has full control of the distance.

What would the best way to replicate this be or how to get the page to scroll that smooth?

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1v01jn2u/1/)

```
var $window = $(window);
var scrollTime = 1.2;
var scrollDistance = 135;

$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/40  || -event.originalEvent.detail/3
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut, // Quart.easeInOut
            overwrite: 5                            
        });

});
```